# PlayFramework Scala: How to get default Hikaricp connection

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I am trying to get connection from default `Hikaricp` config. Following is `application.conf`

```
modules {
  enabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"
  enabled += "play.api.db.HikariCPModule"
  enabled += "modules.AppModule"
}
db.default.hikaricp.dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.user=rp
#db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.url="postgres://rp:password@localhost/profile"
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.password=password
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.databaseName=profile
db.default.hikaricp.dataSource.serverName=localhost
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
```

Since `Play` is maintaining the connection pool. Now I am unable to find a way to get connection created above `Play`. I have tried the following (1, 2, 3):

```
//1. Injecting
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

class DBConnection @Inject()(db: Database) {

}
 // 2. Mentioned here.

object DBConnection {
implicit val db = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current).db
//implicit val db = Database.forConfig("default") (3)
}
```

How can I get connection from the `default` connection pool?

> **Additional Details:**
>   Play Framework version: `2.16.9`
>   Scala version is `2.12.6`
>   Postgres Dependency `org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42`.
>   Added [logs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Hk3a987fE6ADrnSWtcJfTz00Hc7nn5R?usp=sharing) here for all three try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `play.api.db.DBApi`, like:

```
class DatabaseService @Inject()(dbApi: DBApi)
                               (implicit ec: DatabaseExecutionContext) {
   lazy val database = dbApi.database("default")
   ...
}
```